# Solve simple differential equation - Error?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I get the error "The function Te appears with no arguments." when running this code. I'm not sure why. Is it because of the $Abs[\Gamma]$ ?

```
C1 = 10^-10;
C2 = 0.1*C1;
R = 50;
Tb = 0.1;
Geb = 5*10^-15;
Z0 = 50;
L[Te_] := 10^-9 + 10^-9*(Te - 0.1);
Zlcr[Te_, w_] := (1/R + 1/(I*L[Te]*w) + I*C1*w)^-1;
Zload[Te_, w_] := -I*w*C2 + Zlcr[Te, w];
\[CapitalGamma][Te_, w_] := (Zload[Te, w] - Z0)/(Zload[Te, w] + Z0);
y[Te_, w_] := (Abs[\[CapitalGamma][Te, w]])^2;
p[Te_, w_] := Abs[\[CapitalGamma][Te, w]]
Co = 10^-28;
Vol = 10^-21;
Cv = Co/Vol;
eqn1[w_, Te_, Pprobe_, t_] :=  
 Cv*Te'[t] ==   (Cv -   y[Te, w])*5 y[Te, w]* Pprobe
eqn2 = eqn1[3*10^9, Te, 10^-15, t]
sol = DSolve[     {eqn2, Te[0] == 0 }, Te[t], t  ]
```

Comment: Wow! you asked 13 questions and voted only twice! You're not getting useful help here, are you?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Alright, I had no idea about the significance of that. I'll bear that in mind.

Comment: You can easily check [your past questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16374/user44840?tab=questions) and cast your votes _at least_ on their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your last three lines by:

```
eqn1[w_, Te_, Pprobe_, t_] := Cv*Te'[t] == (Cv - y[Te[t], w])*5 y[Te[t], w]*Pprobe
eqn2 = eqn1[3*10^9, Te, 10^-15, t]
sol = NDSolve[{eqn2, Te[0] == 0}, Te[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[Te[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My machine doesn't return a result for the `DSolve[]` after a few seconds, so I turned it into `NDSolve[]`, because your focus wasn't on this issue.

Comment: I'm trying to obtain an expression for $Te(t)$, Why is there a need to put in {t,0,10} in the second last line? I'm thinking shouldn't it simply be: sol = NDSolve[{eqn2, Te[0] == 0}, Te[t], t]

Comment: @user44840 As I commented at the last paragraph on my answer I solved the equation numerically because the key point of your question is answered with my redefinition of `eqn1`. I don't know if `DSolve[]` is able to solve your equation (perhaps just waiting some more time will suffice).

Comment: It seems like $Te(t)$ is a linear function of $t$. I'm expecting it to be something like an exponential decay..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use $Te$ as a variable and as a function in the same time this cause that it appears without argument in the differential equation.

Comment: how can i edit it to fix that?

Comment: I can't really understand your equation. 
$eqn2$ is in the form $f'(t)=g(f)$ which has no meaning (at least for me).
Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: eqn1 is a differential equation with 4 variables to begin with, $w, Te, Pprobe, t$. eqn 2 specifies values of $w, Pprobe$, making it a simple differential equation to solve for $Te(t)$

Comment: I do understand that but what is $Te$ ?  because you treat it as a number at the first and as a function at last.

Comment: $Te$ is not a number. It is a variable to be solved, like $x(t)$

Comment: Then why you wrote 
L[Te_] := 10^-9 + 10^-9*(Te - 0.1);

Comment: $L(Te)$ is a function of $Te$, which makes $y(Te,w)$. L goes into Zlcr and Zload, which goes into gamma, which goes into y which goes into equation.